# Not able to replace String from file while iterating

Tags: bash, shell, replace

The final.txt looks like:

```
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping/camping.design
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

I would like to replace only replace the files which contains `/aura/` in its line to `src/aura/camping`

```
if [ -e final.txt ]
then
        ARRAY=()
        while read CFILE
            do
                    echo Analyzing file `basename $CFILE`
                    case "$CFILE"
                    in
                        *.design) TYPENAME="AuraDefinitionBundle";;
                        *) TYPENAME="UNKNOWN";;
                    esac

                    if [ "$TYPENAME" == "AuraDefinitionBundle" ]
                        then
                                if [ $(contains "${ARRAY[@]}" $(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")) != "y" ]
                                then
                                    echo baseFile from new method cFile $CFILE
                                    CFILENAME="$CFILE"

                                    replace="src/aura/"$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")
                                    echo checkChanges "${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
                                    CFILE="${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
                                    echo baseFile from after change method cFile $CFILE
                                else
                                    continue
                                fi
                        fi
            done < final.txt
else
echo Change file not found!
```

This works, so I can see this in the window now:

```
 [exec] baseFile from new method cFile src/aura/camping/camping.design
 [exec] checkChanges src/aura/camping
 [exec] baseFile from after change method cFile src/aura/camping
```

But the file `final.txt` does not change:

```
build/create_changes.sh
build/create_changes.sh-meta.xml
src/aura/camping/camping.design
src/aura/camping/camping.design-meta.xml
```

I replaced it right there `CFILE="${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"`

Tried this too :

```
if [ $(contains "${ARRAY[@]}" $(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")) != "y" ]
then
    CFILENAME="$CFILE"
    ARRAY+=($(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")"))
    replace="src/aura/"$(basename -- "$(dirname -- "$CFILE")")
    #CFILE="${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
    sed -i 's/$CFILENAME/$replace/' final.txt
else
    continue
fi
```

Am I missing something more here?

Comment: are you trying to change the contents of `final.txt`? or are you trying to change the contents of the files listed in `final.txt`? if the former, please show the 'before' and 'after' contents of `final.txt`; at the beginning of your post you mention wanting to replace `/aura/` with `src/aura/camping` ... but that string is already in `final.txt` ... do you really want to change `src/aura/camping/camping.design` to `srcsrc/aura/campingcamping/camping.design` (note the double `src` and `camping` strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt has been good for the most parts, but the part involving changing the file content is incorrect in both the attempts.

#### `Problem 1`

You were surprised that the below attempt did not replace the contents of the file. It won't.

```
CFILE="${CFILENAME/$CFILENAME/"$replace"}"
```

Because the above is a `bash` internal construct for string replacement. It just replaces the string contents stored in the variable `CFILENAME` and puts the result to `CFILE`. No file modification is done at all.

Judging from your inputs your `CFILENAME` input would be `src/aura/camping/camping.design` and the `replace` variable would be `src/aura/camping`. Doing the above would put the string `src/aura/camping` to the variable `CFILE` and *not* to the file pointed by the variable `CFILE`.

#### `Problem 2`

You seemed to have identified that `sed` would solve your problem, which is in the right track, but you seemed to have missed a couple of tricks.

1. You have variables defined in your `sed` search and replacement parts, but the problem is with the quotes. Variables in `bash` shell don't expand when single quoted but only with double-quotes.
2. The next problem is with the de-limiter string used in `sed`, which is by default `/`. But remember both your source and replacement strings have `/` present, so `sed` would not understand what is the original and replacement text. You need to define a de-limiter that is not `/` and also any meta-character that is not part of your string. I would recommend `|` in your case

   ```
   sed "s|$CFILENAME|$replace|" final.txt
   ```
3. Now the biggest problem is with the `-i` flag in your `sed` command which means in-place editing of your files whiles. Remember you are reading the file in a loop with a `while read` construct line by line and now your editing this file after parsing each line. You are messing up with the shell re-direction in a wrong way here. The ideal way would be re-direct your line by line edits to a temporary file and move it to your original file once the loop is done.

   ```
   sed "s|$CFILENAME|$replace|" final.txt >> temp_final.txt
   ```

Something like above using `>>` which appends to a file. And once the loop is finished, revert to your original file using `mv`

```
mv -- temp_final.txt final.txt
```